# Chromecast Sample Project not casting on tv

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I am new for chromecast and trying to run the sample master app present on git hub.

I have followed all the steps...

1)import google cast sdk 
2)import both libraries... appcompat, mediarouter
     Used these as libraries in the sample project.
but having confusion.
I want to work only on sender app

1)whats the app id in the sample.
2)If I run the project it compiles and run without errors but not casting anything on Tv.

I am simply running the Github project.

Kindly help me.